# Codeigniter ajax form submit unwanted post with jquery cookie for CSRF

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

So i have an issue that when I use the $.cookie jquery plugin my form seems to submit wrongly by submitting early I think.

So my form is:

```
<?php
    echo form_open($this->uri->uri_string(), 'class="ajax_email_submission"');
    ?>
    <div id="email_newsletter_signup" class="ajax_email_block_signup" >
        <h3>Sign up to the newsletter:</h3>
        <?php echo form_error('signup_email','<div id="email_error" class="error">','</div>');?>
        <h3>email: <input id="users_email_address" type="email" name="signup_email" value="<?php echo set_value('signup_email'); ?>" placeholder="Your email"/> </h3>

        <input id="email_submit" type="submit" name="submit"/>
    </div>
    <?php
    echo form_close();
?>
```

The JS is

```
$(document).ready(function()
{    
    $('#email_submit').click(function() 
    {
        alert('1');
        var form_data = 
        {
           users_email: $('#users_email_address').val(),
           csrf_test_name: $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name')
        };
        alert('2');
        $.ajax
        ({
            url: 'NewsLetter/submit',
            type: 'POST',
            data: form_data,
            success: function(msg)
            {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function(msg)
            {
                alert('error');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

The method exists and if i put in localhost/myzone/NewsLetter/submit the method submit works properly.

When I look in the codeigniter Router class I find that the $_POST variable contains:

```
$_POST  array[3]        
ci_csrf_token   string  "3dad64d9aaaaaaaaaaaaaad2082ae55c"  
signup_email    string  "mail@cheeeese.com" 
submit  string  "Submit"
```

The URI that is submitted is localhost/myzone/NewsLetter as the submit is in the post and not the URI so I get sent to the index method instead of the submit method.

Also what happens in the JS you may notice the `alert('1')` and `alert('2')`. Only `alert('1')` shows which I have no clue why this happens!

All help is really appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You submit form not by ajax but by POST method. If you  want to do smth BEFORE submiting, add

```
event.preventDefault()
```

to your click function. Like

```
$('#email_submit').click(function(event) 
{
    event.preventDefault();

    //all your calculations and ajax than
}
```

Than no form will be submited and you will push your ajax request

Comment: Just wondering why the call to the cookie pushes the Ajax call and doesn't signal the second alert